# Unable to locate element by xpath

Tags: xpath

Here is source html:

```
<div id="alert_signin" class="alert_modal_error">
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        Invalid username or password.
    </div>
</div>
```

What I really need is to check if message "Invalid username or password." appears (python + selenium webdriver ). But I was unlucky to find it using xpath like

```
find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id=\'alert_signin\']/div[@class=\'alert\']').text
```

So I've decided to find exact xpath using message text. I've tried several options like

```
find_element_by_xpath('//*[text()[contains(.,\'Invalid\')]]')
```

or

```
find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(., \'Invalid username or password.\')]')
```

but each time got "NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector": blablabla"

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *cannot directly point your expressions to the text nodes in Selenium.*

Instead, I would get the entire "alert" text:

```
alert_text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#alert_signin .alert").text
```

Then, you can either apply the "contains" check:

```
assert "Invalid username or password." in alert_text
```

Or, remove the "x" part:

```
alert_text = alert_text.replace(u"×", "").strip()
assert alert_text == "Invalid username or password."
```

Examples in Python.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about alert_text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".alert_signin .alert").text - it gives me NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".alert_signin .alert"}

Comment: @yegres ah, yeah, was a mistake in the selector - check it out now. Thanks.

Comment: same result ( please note all div elements from description are nested.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some more info, please:

-- Is there a button that you click to get the message?

-- Is the message within a browser-specific alert, or is it a displayed text on the page?

(if the latter is the case, try something like `if "Invalid username or password." in driver.page_source: print "SUCCESS!")`

Answer (score 0):

actually what I've found is that the only thing I need is using implicitly_wait.
this code works fine:

```
sign_in.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
alert_text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#alert_signin > div.alert.alert-danger.alert-dismissable").text
alert_text = alert_text.replace(u"×", "").strip()
assert alert_text == "Invalid username or password."
```

however note from **alecxe** was very useful while I was trying to verify my approach

> You cannot directly point your expressions to the text nodes in Selenium.